# Tabs Focus Behaviour problem by fragment next focus up on tab layout

Tags: java, android, fragment, ott, tablayout

I have Home, Movies, Live TV, TV Guide, Apps & Games Tabs and on every click on tab I open fragment which contains multiple rail like Bollywood Movies Rail and others rail also and when I press up button fragment rail focus goes on tab above rail data like it goes to all home, movies, live tv tab and i want to make that if i opened a movies fragment by clicking on movies tab so on pressing up button my focus should go to movies tab not on other tab HOW TO FIX THIS !

I try to customize my XML Files by implementing next focus up on tab but it didn't work.